# VoiceOver cursor not in sync with they keyboard focus

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior of the VoiceOver cursor - even though I have the "sync keyboard focus and voice over cursor" option enabled, some elements are simply skipped by the VoiceOver when using `Tab` to navigate. When a problematic element is focused with a keyboard, the VoiceOver cursor simply stays on the previously focused element and moves further when the next element is focused.

There are also elements that are skipped by VO when going top to bottom of the page but they are focused when going in the other direction. The elements in question have appropriate roles and tabindexes and are visible in the accessibility tree.

What could be the reason for such behavior of the VoiceOver cursor?

Comment: Can you make a demo video?

Comment: @slugolicious: sadly I can't since it's a part of the app that hasn't been published yet